# Full GC duration difference in same JVM

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

Why is the amount of time to complete full GC varies significantly in same JVM

We got 8GB heap Sun JVM.
 Some times it is 13 seconds and rarely (once a week) it is 530 seconds.  This long FULL GCs is causing some communication issue in our clustered environment. Is the difference in resource availability (like cpu cycles non availability etc ) when Full GC occurs is causing this issue? Whether changing our gc parameters will help? . Please find our gc parameters below.

example:

157858.158: [**Full GC 157858.158**: [Tenured: 5567918K->2718558K(5593088K), **13.4078854** secs] 7042362K->2718558K(7689728K), [Perm : 202405K->202405K(524288K)], 13.4079752 secs]

683185.700: [**Full GC 683185.700**: [Tenured: 5584345K->2461609K(5593088K), **536.8253698** secs] 7028566K->2461609K(7689728K), [Perm : 242259K->242259K(524288K)], 536.8254562 secs]

Environment:
We are running a application on SAP Netweaver Server  - Sun JVM.

java -version

```
java version "1.4.2_19-rev"
Java(TM) Platform, Standard Edition for Business (build 1.4.2_19-rev-b0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.4.2_19-rev-b07, mixed mode)
```

JVM parameters:

```
Xmx8192M
-Xms8192M
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-XX:NewSize=2730M
-XX:MaxNewSize=2730M
-Djco.jarm=1
-XX:SurvivorRatio=2
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+HandlePromotionFailure
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=32
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-Xss2M
-XX:CompilerThreadStackSize=4096
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.security.policy=./java.policy
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.sap.engine.system.ORBProxy
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.sap.engine.system.ORBSingletonProxy
-Djavax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass=com.sap.engine.system.PortableRemoteObjectProxy
-Dvr2m.meta.directory.class=com.vendavo.core.util.VenMetaDir
-Dvr2m.home=E:\Vendavo
-Djasper.reports.compile.class.path=E:\<>\jasperreports\v1.2.5\jasperreports    -1.2.5.jar;E:\<dsaf>iReport\v1.2.4\iReport-    1.2.4.jar;E:\<dsaf>\iReport\v1.2.4\itext-1.3.1.jar;E:\<dsaf>\classes\jars\abc.jar;
-Dvr2m.cluster.mynodename=n1_server101
-XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Below is the same tenuring distribution. Not sure of the way to send the complete GC logs.

```
Desired survivor size 644087808 bytes, new threshold 10 (max 10)
- age   1:   17299744 bytes,   17299744 total
- age   2:    4327344 bytes,   21627088 total
- age   3:    2152536 bytes,   23779624 total
- age   4:    1291104 bytes,   25070728 total
- age   5:    2277184 bytes,   27347912 total
- age   6:    8323128 bytes,   35671040 total
- age   9:    1859888 bytes,   37530928 total
- age  10:    2849376 bytes,   40380304 total
: 1465272K->39817K(2096640K), 0.0317708 secs] 7042426K->5619506K(7689728K), 0.0318546     secs]
682873.961: [GC 682873.961: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 644087808 bytes, new threshold 10 (max 10)
- age   1:   17629648 bytes,   17629648 total
- age   2:    1937560 bytes,   19567208 total
- age   3:    4322600 bytes,   23889808 total
- age   4:    2051048 bytes,   25940856 total
- age   5:     910360 bytes,   26851216 total
- age   6:    2237400 bytes,   29088616 total
- age   7:    8322776 bytes,   37411392 total
- age  10:    1859936 bytes,   39271328 total
: 1437577K->38693K(2096640K), 0.0363818 secs] 7017266K->5621199K(7689728K), 0.0364742     secs]
683032.408: [GC 683032.408: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 644087808 bytes, new threshold 10 (max 10)
- age   1:   27372472 bytes,   27372472 total
- age   2:     414904 bytes,   27787376 total
- age   3:    1828208 bytes,   29615584 total
- age   4:    4318504 bytes,   33934088 total
- age   5:    2051520 bytes,   35985608 total
- age   6:     760512 bytes,   36746120 total
- age   7:    2153392 bytes,   38899512 total
- age   8:    8322232 bytes,   47221744 total
: 1436453K->46460K(2096640K), 0.0555022 secs] 7018959K->5630806K(7689728K), 0.0555993 secs]
683185.700: [Full GC 683185.700: [Tenured: 5584345K->2461609K(5593088K), 536.8253698     secs] 7028566K->2461609K(7689728K), [Perm : 242259K->242259K(524288K)], 536.8254562 secs]
684682.569: [GC 684682.569: [ParNew
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like "promotion failure" syndrom.

GC has two cycles

- **young GC** or **minor GC**, collects garbage in young space
- **full GC** collects both young and old (if Mark Sweep Compact algorithm is chosen as in your configuration)

*Young GC* promotes some live objects to old space

- if they have been tenured long enough
- or in case if too much objects have survived and **survivor subspace** of **young space** cannot accommodate them

Normally JVM estimates amount of free space in **old space** it needs for **young collection** and starts **full GC** if free memory is low.

But if that estimate is wrong free space in **old space** can get exhausted in the middle of young collection.

In this case JVM have to **rollback** young collection and start full collection. During work of copy collection (used for young collection) object graph is not consistent and mark sweep compact cannot start until graph is fixed to consistent state.

Unfortunately this roll back could take order of magnitude longer than normal **full GC**.

This problem is typical for Concurrent Mark Sweep collector, but may affect Mark Sweep Compact too.

*UPDATE*
Looking at your GC logs and tenuring distribution, I would suggest you to reduce young space (and thus scale of potential "rollback").

Judging from your logs cutting young space down 3 times may be reasonable. `-XX:NewSize=900M -XX:MaxNewSize=900M`

Upgrading JVM would be another good options (failure prediction logic has likely been improved since 1.4 times).

Below are few links related to GC in HotSpot JVM:

- [Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's minor GC](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html)
- [Garbage collection in HotSpot JVM](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html)
- [How to tame java GC pauses? Surviving 16GiB heap and greater](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-tame-java-gc-pauses)

Comment: Thanks Alexey, So Whether increase in tenured space will help or it will just postpone this long Full GC to few more hours ?   Should we live with it or just change the choice of GC policy ?

Comment: You are running an ancient version of JVM and have unusual GC configuration (probably implied by specific of application), so I'm not confident enough to advise particular options. Increasing old space probably won't help much (promotion failure could happen to random full GC). Could you share your tenuring distribution logs, they may help me to better understand problem?

Comment: Please find it at the bottom of the original question.I just pasted it.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. I will try this out.  Your answer was educational.